# What is the proper term for when an animal is "pregnant" with eggs instead of live young?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Specifically things like chicken or most fish.

Comment: @Hugh What about viviparous animals like vipers or scorpions? Are they pregnant?

Comment: @AlainPannetierΦ that's the word for the animals themselves that give birth by eggs (and viviparous describing animals with live births), not the state of the animal right before the proto-animals are expelled. The latter is what the OP is looking for, i.e. the synonym of pregnant but when you're about to pop out some eggs rather than a live child.

Comment: What makes you think *pregnant* doesn’t work for anything but humans? The OED has this for pregnant: “That has conceived in the womb; with child or with young; gravid. Const. *with*, *of* (the offspring), *by* (the male parent).”

Comment: @tchrist while I'd have no problem calling a female giraffe, horse, cat etc. *pregnant*, I would hesitate before calling a hen *pregnant*.

Comment: The real answer is pr**egg**nant, obviously.

Comment: @CoDEmanX - This is getting silly now but I have to admit that was quite funny!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

gravid

/ˈɡravɪd/

adjective

adjective: gravid

  1.

technical
carrying eggs or young; pregnant.
"the retroverted gravid uterus"

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gravid)

Comment: "Technical" is right. I've watched a *lot* of documentaries and I've never heard this word (OTOH, or at least, did not comprehended it if I did).

Comment: It's one of those things you know or don't. I saw once saw a TV programme about the life cycle of the salmon and it was mentioned then!

Comment: IIRC, Attenborough prefers *'laden with eggs'* ;)

Comment: "Gravid" came instantly to mind when I saw this question.  I think it's fairly well known and understood.  (Probably avoided in documentaries, though, to keep the "grade level" of the language below some threshold.)

Comment: *Gravid* and *pregnant* are identical in meaning. The OED has for *gravid* the following: **“Pregnant,** heavy with young.” And its sense for *pregnant* also mentions *gravid*. These are no different.

Comment: @Mazura "Quite laden indeed."

Comment: @tchrist - The question is, do eggs count as 'young'? I don't think they do. A very brief dictionary search seems to support me. Gravid works for egg-laying creatures as required by the title of the question. I don't believe 'pregnant' applies to crocodiles for instance.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK If you google  *pregnant crocodile*, you get results.

Comment: @tchrist - If you google *flying crocodile* you get results! https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2449/4011866770_41729e0fb6_z.jpg?zz=1 ---> I'm not sure what that proves. ;-)

Comment: The people I work with knew the word "gravid" and appreciated the difference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have often heard the words "gravid" and "pregnant" used by herpetologists, to describe a lizard or a snake not long to lay eggs.

Answer (score 8):

**in lay** (entry 'lay' section *phrases*
(of a hen) laying eggs regularly.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lay

Definition of **gravid** in English:
adjective
1 technical Carrying eggs or young; pregnant: the retroverted gravid uterus

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gravid

Comment: @Chasly,   "gravid" beaten 'by a head.' Well done.  Have you found the term for crocodiles? That has me flummoxed.

Comment: Try searching for "gravid crocodile" ---> http://reptilesofaustralia.com/crocs/johnstoni.htm#.VczwnV6FMuQ ---> second photo :-)

Comment: (What does "spawn" have to do with anything?)  Regarding "in lay" - Hugh are you sure that means what the OP asks?  Doesn't it just mean "they are currently (as in "this month") producing eggs"?  (So, when "in lay" then in that case from time to time (say, Mondays and Wednesdays from 4pm - 9pm) a given hen would be gravid, and other hours/days, would not be gravid.)  It seems to be quite different from "gravid" (ie, "'pregnant' with an egg" at this moment).

Comment: @JoeBlow I think an egg takes more than a day to develop (apart from the shell) and so the hen is gravid with all the eggs, yolk and all in their egg-sacs, which are being developed.

Answer (score 4):

From the oxford dictionary:

> [**oviparous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/oviparous) - producing young by means of eggs that are hatched after they have been laid by the parent
>
> [**viviparous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/viviparous) bringing forth live young that have developed inside the body of the parent

Comment: good words, next time include the definitions :)

Comment: Although they're good words they don't actually answer the question. A species may be described as oviparous, but not as pregnant. An individual described as viviparous may not actually be expecting.

Comment: IMO, a complete answer would begin with this information. Plus one; extremely relevant.

Comment: Compare as well with ovoviviparous!  Fascinating! http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ovoviviparous

Comment: As Chris points out, this answer is, very simply, **completely wrong**.  I'm really sick of **utterly incorrect answers being velocity upvoted** on this site. It's amazingly tedious, and, frankly, stupid.  Now that the poster knows this answer is totally wrong, click the delete button.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't especially refer to fish, birds, or the like, the French loanword **enceinte** is quite useful.

enceinte. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved August 18 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enceinte

Its probable etymology from Latin *incincta* "ungirded" alludes to the gravid female's preparation for imminent parturition.

Answer (score 2):

Gravid always works, for pregnant mammals,reptiles, birds, fish...any creature  that bears young. It is well-understood by veterinarians and lay-people. It does not come with the "human-only" baggage that "pregnant" does.

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Comment: Still, so many other bad answers and comments were given, it's good that the correct answer was given again.

Answer (score 1):

I endorse "gravid" since I've heard it used to indicate oviparous females with eggs. The implication is fertile eggs but they needn't be. Possessing eggs which have not yet been laid. Proper for any egg layer, be it a queen ant, octopus, blue-footed booby, alligator, shark (those that don't do live birth...) or platypus & echidna.

According to Merriam-Webster's site, from:

"Latin gravidus, from gravis heavy. First Known Use: 1597"

But note that this is after 100+ years after "pregnant":

"Middle English, from Latin praegnant-, praegnans carrying a fetus, alteration of praegnas, from prae- pre- + -gnas (akin to gignere to give birth to) — more at kin. First Known Use: 14th century".

There are plenty of synonyms - heavy, quick, big, with child. I remember reading that one of the common ones, "Expecting"?  was a Victorian circumlocution, because pregnancy was too "bodily" for polite society. Overall, I think we're better off leaving that sort of thinking behind us. Aesthetically, I like "With child".

Comment: It's good that you endorse gravid, since a glance at a dictionary shows that is indeed the answer.   BTW regarding your synonyms in the final paragraph, they do not apply at all to the "egg" case.